# jquerymobile how to bind and unbind a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

In my mobilejquery project, I need to unbind the links (hrefs), and bind them a point, for that, I use this code:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {

    $('a[href="#"], a.disabled').bind('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();    //sets all dynamic href to prevents wrong url
    } )
});
```

but not at all works... anything wrong with my code?

Additional question..

I don't want to show the url path in the navigator.. is there any way to make the url path not to show?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

did you try using the [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method?

```
$('a[href="#"], a.disabled').unbind("click").bind('click',function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();    //sets all dynamic href to prevents wrong url
} )
```